# How to prove an inequality with $\tanh(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that thre existts a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\tanh(\frac{t}{2}) - \frac{t}{2} < -c\frac{t}{2}$$

for all $t\ge 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothe that

$$\tanh \frac{t}2 - \frac{t}2  < -c\frac{t}2 \iff f(t)=\frac{\tanh \frac{t}2  - \frac{t}2 }{\frac{t}2 }<-c$$

which is true for some c>0, indeed

- $f(t)$ is continuos for $t \ge 1$
- $\tanh x<x \implies f(t)<\frac{\frac{t}2  - \frac{t}2
     }{\frac{t}2 }=0 $
- $\lim_{t\to +\infty} f(t)=-1$

thus for [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) $f(x)$ is bounded wih a maximum $M<0$ thus exists $c>0$ such that $0<-c<M\le f(t)$.

Comment: how did you prove that with  $c=1$ the inequality is true? thanks

Comment: You can prove that c=1 is the optimum by studing f(x), for the existence you need only to consider that $f(x)$ is continuos and the limit at $0$ and $ \infty$ are finite.

Comment: if so we have $\tanh(x)<0$? how did you find the limit as $x\to +\infty$?

Comment: @siwar since for$ x\to +\infty$ we have $\tanh x \to 1$ $$\frac{\tanh x - x}{x}=\frac{\frac{\tanh x}{x} - 1}{1}\to -1$$

Comment: why $\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\to 0$?

Comment: @siwar note that $\tanh x \to 1$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: for $c=1$, the inequality is $\tanh(t/2)<0$, which is false for every $t>0$.

Comment: @egreg You are right, I can't find my mistake now. In any case the following is correct, in the sense that f(x) is bounded and c exists, do you agree with it. Thanks!

Comment: @siwar This answer is wrong.

Comment: @egreg It is not completely wrong, maybe I need to fix the assumption x=t/2 which is not completely adherent to the given OP but I think that the way to prove is correct. Am I wrong?

Comment: @egreg I've update the solution, does it work now?

Comment: @gimusi It is bounded. And so?

Comment: And so exist c such that $f(x)<-c$, that was what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @gimusi The supremum of $f$ might be $0$. You want an upper bound for $f$, not a lower bound.

Comment: How can be zero if f(x) is strictly less than zero and for $t\to +\infty$ we have that $f(t)\to -1$? Am I loosing something?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=(1-c)x-\tanh x
$$
over $[1/2,\infty)$. Its derivative is $f'(x)=-c+\tanh^2x$. Since, for $x\ge1/2$, $\tanh^2x\ge\tanh^2(1/2)$, the derivative is positive whenever $c<\tanh^2(1/2)$, so the function is increasing.

Since $f(1/2)=(1-c)/2-\tanh(1/2)$, we just need to set
$$
1-c>2\tanh(1/2)
$$
that is, $c<1-2\tanh(1/2)$. Thus any $c$ satisfying
$$
0<c<\min(1-2\tanh(1/2),\tanh^2(1/2))
$$
will do.

Note that
$$
1-2\tanh(1/2)=1-2\frac{e-1}{e+1}=\frac{e+1-2e+2}{e+1}=\frac{3-e}{e+1}>0
$$

Comment: I’ve clarified and completed my point on the existence of c. I don’t think it is necessary consider derivative to show that c exists. Continuity and existence of a negative maximum suffice. Thanks for your observations.